# Bro: Disable reading and writing of .state/state.bst

Tags: bro, zeek

I'm using Bro to crunch a whole lot of pcap files, so I want to run a bunch of instances in parallel, but I'm worried that they will trip over each other accessing the [persistent state file](https://www.bro.org/sphinx-git/script-reference/attributes.html#attr-&persistent) (`.state/state.bst`).  Is there any way to tell Bro that it should neither read nor write any persistent state, no matter what the scripts might want?  I cannot find anything relevant in the manual.  Making `.state` an inaccessible directory has the desired effect, except that (reasonably enough) Bro issues a warning about not being able to get in there, which I would prefer to avoid (I'd have to filter it out at a higher level).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't currently stop the use of this directory, but you can redefine the `state_dir` variable to put it somewhere else. You can conveniently redefine variables at the command line, so you could invoke Bro via something like this:

```
bro -r some.pcap state_dir=$(mktemp -d -p . bro.XXXX)
```

This will make each run use a new state directory in the current directory.

There may be a catch — the DNS manager seems to have a hardcoded `.state` directory, so if your configuration uses this feature (i.e. DNS lookups conducted by Bro itself), the above may not work.